# Passing data from an jQuery Ajax call to an MVC ApiController Action is losing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-apicontroller

First, let me just say that there are many similar questions to this already posted here, but I've tried all of the solutions and have had no joy.

I have an MVC ApiController Action whose signature is:

```
    public void Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
```

I've tried with or without [FromBody].

My Employee class has 5 members of base types, int, string, string, string, double

I am calling the Action from a separate domain (both on my localhost using Cors), using jQuery Ajax as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:55555/api/Employees",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        },
        data: {
            Id: 100,
            FirstName: "Fred",
            LastName: "Blogs",
            Gender: "Male",
            Salary: 100000
        },
        // ...
```

**This works absolutely fine**.  There is no problem with the Authorisation.  The Employee object on the Controller is populated with this data.  But what I want to do is send the data in a more "structured' way.  So my data would look something like this:

```
        data: {
            employee: employee
        },
```

I have tried everything I can think of to format the employee.  Specified all combinations of:

```
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
```

Combined with different ways to "stringify" my employee object:

```
    var employee = {
        Id: 100,
        FirstName: "Fred",
        LastName: "Blogs",
        Gender: "Male",
        Salary: 100000
    };

    employee = JSON.stringify({ "employee": employee });
    employee = JSON.stringify(employee);
```

In case this is related (as a more simple example) I also have this method on my ApiController:

```
public void Delete([FromBody] int employeeId)
```

Again, I am unable to pass the employeeId in the "desired" way.

I can't even get:

```
        data: {
            employeeId: 100
        },
```

To work!?!

I can get the Delete method to work is I change it to [FromUri] and and specify the "?employeeId=100" in the calling Url.

I was hoping that I could be a bit more consistent across the different call and always pass an 'object' in JSON format.

Does anyone have any ideas that may help me progress?

Thanks.

More information on the Delete call.

If I use Postman, remove requirement for Authentication, specify Content-Type "application/json"
in the header and employeeId = 100 in the body, Postman returns:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'employeeId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void Delete(Int32)' in 'WebApi.Controllers.EmployeesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "DELETE" passes a body like a "POST" so the [FromBody] wont work if you are calling the ajax call with the type: "Delete".

As for the employee post call,  I have seen similar issues.  The only work around I could find was to make a wrapper class that wraps the employee.

```
public class EmployeeWrapper {
    public Employee employee {get; set;}
}
```

Then you have EmployeeWrapper be the parameter for the Post method.

```
 public void Post([FromBody] EmployeeWrapper employeeWrapper)  {
      Employee employee = employeeWrapper.employee;
      ...
```

This lets you call with the ajax data:

```
data: {
        employee: employee
    },
```

Comment: **This worked**.  As you seem to indicate though, this is a bit messy.  I would of thought that one of the stringify() options on the client side would format the data in a way I could use the Employee object directly.

Comment: Fair comment about Delete().  I'll investigate later.  I assume Post/Put should work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change `data` to this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ employee : employee })
```

Comment: I tried this.  Again with all combinations of dataType / contentType.  The method is called, but all of the properties of the Employee object still have their default null, 0 values within the ApiController Action.

Comment: try adding `contentType: 'application/json', dataType: "json"` to your `$.ajax` setup

Comment: Still the employee object on the Server has default values:

        var employee = {
            Id: 100,
            FirstName: "Fred",
            LastName: "Blogs"
            Gender: "Male",
            Salary: 100000
        };
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://...,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ employee: employee }),

Answer (score 0):

The following combination finally fixed my issue.

```
    var employee = {
        Id: 100,
        FirstName: "Fred",
        LastName: "Blogs",
        Gender: "Male",
        Salary: 100000
    };

    employee = JSON.stringify(employee);

    //...
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: employee,
    //...
```

One of the reason's I did not arrive at this earlier, was that I was tending to surround the data: { ... } with curly braces.  This was causing it to fail.

Also managed to get the DELETE working in the Body of message in exactly the same way.